# My getter is being initialized back to zero?

Tags: java, getter-setter

So I have a bunch of classes used for an animal hospital. My superClass, Pet, has four constants, MALE, FEMALE, SPAYED, NEUTERED, that are set to numbers. When a data file is read in, in my AnimalHospitalClass, it is supposed to set the gender to a number, go back to the Pet class compare the "sexId" to the constant, and then return the gender. The issue Im having is not logical but technical. For some reason my setter is (setSex(sexID)) is getting the number that my gender is set to, but when I try to make the if statements in my getter to compare the numbers and return the gender, the sexID ( which is a variable in the Pet class) is set back to 0, instead of what I set it to.

heres my Pet Class:

```
     public class Pet{
 private String petName;
 private String ownerName;
 private String color;
 protected int sexID;

 public static final int MALE = 1;
 public static final int FEMALE = 2;
 public static final int SPAYED = 3;
 public static final int NEUTERED = 4;


 public Pet(String petName, String ownerName, String color){
      this.petName = petName;
      this.ownerName = ownerName;
      this.color = color;
  }

 // getters
 public String getPetName(){
      return petName;
 }
 public String getOwnerName(){
      return ownerName;
  }
  public String getColor(){
      return color;
  }

  public String getSex(){
  /* this is where I am having issues, instead of sexID being set to what
   it is in the setter, it is set back to 0*/
  System.out.println("SEXID: " + sexID); // will print 0
      if(sexID == MALE){
           return("male " );
      }
      else if(sexID == FEMALE){
           return("female");
      }
     else  if(sexID == SPAYED){
           return("spayed");
      }
     else if(sexID == NEUTERED){
           return("neutered");
      }

     else{ // will print else only since sexID is equal to 0 
      return("Not Available. " + sexID); 
// in case there is no gender in the file
     }
  }

  public void setSex(int sexID){
      this.sexID = sexID;
      System.out.println("SEX: " + sexID); // this will print the correct
                                      // sexID that was set in the other class        


    }

  public String toString(){
      return(petName + "owned by " + ownerName
             + "\nColor: " + color
             +"\nSex: " + getSex() );
   }
  }
```

here is my Animal hospital class (only one method since it is large):

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
     public class AnimalHospital{
         Scanner input;

        private String pName;
private String pName2;
private String oName;
private String color ;
private String specialType; // store hair length for cats, size for dogs
private String gender;
private String type; // finds CAT, DOG, BIRD




public AnimalHospital(String inputFile)throws FileNotFoundException{

    input = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));

}
     public void printPetInfoByOwner(String name){

     Pet pet = new Pet(pName,oName,color);

     while(input.hasNext()){
        String type = input.next(); // finds Cat, Dog, Bird
        pName = input.next(); // gets pet name
        oName = input.next(); // gets owner name
        color = input.next();
        gender = input.next();

         if(gender.equals("male")){   // this is where I set the gender
           int male = 1;           // to a number so I can compare

           pet.setSex(male);
        }
         if(gender.equals("female")){
           int female = 2;

           pet.setSex(female);

        }
         if(gender.equals("spayed")){
           int spayed = 3;

          pet.setSex(spayed);
        }
         if(gender.equals("neutered")){
           int neutered = 4;

          pet.setSex(neutered);
        }

         if(!(type.equals("BIRD"))){
        specialType = input.next(); // since Bird does not have a special type
        }
        if(type.equals("CAT") && oName.equals(name)){
            Cat cat = new Cat(pName, oName, color, specialType);

             System.out.println(cat.toString());
            break;

        }
        if(type.equals("DOG") && oName.equals(name)){
            Dog d = new Dog(pName, oName, color, specialType);

            System.out.println(d.toString());
            break;

        }
        if(type.equals("BIRD") && oName.equals(name)){
            Bird b = new Bird(pName, oName, color);

            System.out.println(b.toString());
            break;

        }



    }

}
```

here is an example output:

```
   CAT: Busker owned by Samantha
   Color: Black
   Sex: Not Available. 0 // reads sex as 0 should be 2, and female
   Hair: short
   AnimalHospital@55f96302 // also how do I get rid of this?
```

Note:

This is an assignment, and I understand if you don't want to give me the answer, any hints would be helpful, but I've thought about this for days and can't figure it out.

thanks!

Comment: 1) Give AnimalHospital a `public String toString()` method that makes sense that returns a String that fully describes the state of the current class.

Comment: 2) Use enums instead of magic `int` constants.

Comment: I'd verify what `gender = input.next();` is actually getting assigned.  I'd also verify that `setSex` is actually getting called as a result

Comment: Btw your getter and setter use different types (String vs int). That's a very bad idea.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did verify that gender is getting assigned correctly i will make sure to see if setSex is actually getting called though

Comment: @Federico That is the way my assignment is set up!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I can't add any additional methods

Comment: As JBNizet says, I think you need to create an instance of the type of Pet first and assign it's sex property

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the sex on the `pet` variable, of type Pet. Then you create a Cat, Bird or Dog, never set its sex, and print it. So, since you never set the sex of the Cat, Bird or Dog, it's 0.

Comment: the toString in my Cat class calls super.getSex()?

Comment: @thatsnifty, a new instance of `Cat` is not the superclass of your `Pet` instance. You created two separate objects in separate memory locations. `super.getSex()` tells the program to run the code defined in the parent class against the current object, `cat` in this case. Study the difference between classes and objects. You're assuming incorrectly that all instances of your subclass refer to one instance of the parent class. If this was the case, which object does `super` refer to when you create two or more instances of `Pet`?

Comment: Meh.  Meant to say... A new instance of `Cat` is not a subclass of your `Pet` instance.  Instance is another way to say object, not class.